# Ngclass function with 2 objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class, ng-style

is it possible to  add  2 objects to  an  ngclass  function  like
`<div class="progress-bar"[ngClass]="getProgressValues(obj.val1,obj.val2)"> </div>`
i get a Json  error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

i tried  "{"val1":1, "val2":2}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix double and single quotes: if you use double quotes as an outer delimiter of the `ngClass` value, use single quotes for the attributes. If you use single quotes as an outer delimiter of the `ngClass` value, use double quotes for the attributes. (or, if there isn't any dash in the attributes' names, use none of them).

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma619835186433166)

```html
<section [ngClass]="{val1: 1, 'other-att': 2}"></section>
```

From the point of view of the API, the values of the object attributes used with `ngClass` should be `true` or `false`. In the case above all of them are truthy, so `val1` and `other-att` classes will be applied (and it works, with no errors). But it makes more sense if you use `true` or `false` as their values:

```html
<section [ngClass]="{c1: true, 'c-2': true, 'c3': false}"></section>
```

If you want to use a function, that's ok too:

```html
<section [ngClass]="_getMyCssClasses()"></section>
```

```js
_getMyCssClasses(): {[className: string]: boolean} {
  return {c1: true, 'c-2': true, 'c3': false};
}
```

Per comments, you want to dynamically set some properties to your element. A more appropriate way to do that is with `style` or `ngStyle`. See the Stackblitz demo above to see it in action.

```html
<div [ngStyle]="getProgressValues(obj.val1,obj.val2)"> </div>
```

```js
getProgressValues(min: number, max: number) {
  return {
    'aria-valuemin': min,
    'aria-valuemax': max
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work...  in  the described function, it still responds with the same  error JSON  error code

Comment: I'm gonna build up a stackblitz example.

Comment: I've put an example together. I hope it makes it a little bit clear. BTW, I understood that you just want to apply CSS classes to your element. If that's not the case, you need to provide more info about what you wanna do.

Comment: thank  you  very much...  [ngClass]="getHeightValues({'cur':2,'max':3})"  i want to  return the  color  code

Comment: oh... in that case, you wanna use `style` or `ngStyle`. I'll put that in my answer.

Comment: [ngStyle]="{'width':Var, 'aria-valuemin':'0','aria-valuemax':'100'}  is what im using at the moment  thats working thank  you  for  your answer...!!